# How to get the Refresh Token with the django-graphql-social-auth library

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt

Hi I am using the [django-graphql-social-auth](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-social-auth) library and whenever I create a social user using this mutation:

```
import graphene
import graphql_social_auth


class Mutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    social_auth = graphql_social_auth.SocialAuthJWT.Field()
```

and this Graphql mutation:

```
mutation SocialAuth($provider: String!, $accessToken: String!) {
  socialAuth(provider: $provider, accessToken: $accessToken) {
    social {
      uid
    }  
    token
    refreshToken
    }
 }
```

I get this error:

```
    {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"refreshToken\" on type \"SocialAuthJWT\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 29,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi @Roy, im just wondering the use case of your social login. Do you use it only for account sign up then backend assign it's own token for api calling? or you actually consume respective platform's social API?

Comment: Hi @TommyLeong I already fixed the issue and it works pretty cool now, you can check my just updated answer. Backend consumes respective platform's social API but that's a separate case, I needed the API also to give their respective app tokens (not the ones of the platform's social API) in order to create a token and refreshtoken system between my app and my API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

```
    # Social authentication
class SocialAuth(graphql_social_auth.SocialAuthMutation):
    token = graphene.String()
    refresh_token = graphene.String()

    @classmethod
    def resolve(cls, root, info, social, **kwargs):
        if social.user.refresh_tokens.count() >= 1:
            return cls(token=get_token(social.user), refresh_token=social.user.refresh_tokens.last())
        else:
            return cls(token=get_token(social.user), refresh_token=create_refresh_token(social.user))
```